# Android: How to remove end blank space from Textview with marquee

Tags: android, textview

I have created TextView with marquee, but I want to remove the blank space between end and start showing the text again.

Here is the screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfdT8.png

Here is my layout

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="dkfjdkf jdfjfsfjkfa asdfjakjfdkasf sfdjaskfjdksf sfdjsfjk gfhgfhfai ggfghgf" />
```

Comment: Try next workaround, if it acceptable for you.
You should create text that contains 2 or 3 your target phrases.
for example your phrase is "Hello world" you should create "Hello world Hello world Hello world" and set it to TextView

Comment: can you show us your complete layout file.. you probably must be missing some constraints.

Comment: Here is my layout 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dkfjdkf jdfjfsfjkfa asdfjakjfdkasf sfdjaskfjdksf sfdjsfjk  gfhgfhfai ggfghgf"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 />

Comment: i think what @123456 is looking for is something like setSpacing(0) to remove the gap between end and start of the text, is the solution found?
 I want it too.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If by blank space you're referring to those black stripes before and after the TextView, you can adjust your layout witdh to 
            **android:layout_width="match_parent"**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="dkfjdkf jdfjfsfjkfa asdfjakjfdkasf sfdjaskfjdksf sfdjsfjk gfhgfhfai ggfghgf" />
```

Also, make sure the parent layout of that TextView is not **applying any margins**

Comment: Nothing change with match_parent

Answer (score 0):

**This solution works up until API 28** when they introduced [restrictions on non-SDK interfaces](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

---

I ran into the same problem and I couldn't find a solution online.  I managed to solve the problem myself by looking at the [source code for TextView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) and referencing [other answers that provide an option to control the scroll speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970927/marquee-set-speed).

Looking at the source code, it will set the gap or blank space to be 1/3 the size of your TextView.  So if your TextView is 600 pixels wide, it will create a 200 pixel gap between the start and end of the message.  This solution will aim to make that value configurable.

The tricky part is that the logic you need to override is all within private classes, fields, and methods on the super class.  This makes the solution far less trivial.

Add this class to your project... `CustomTextView.java`

```
public class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private static final float NEW_GAP = 0F;

    Object marqueeObject;
    Field mStatusField;
    Field mGhostStartField;
    Field mMaxScrollField;
    Field mGhostOffsetField;
    Field mFadeStopField;
    Field mMaxFadeScrollField;

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setSelected(true);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setSelected(true);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setSelected(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            initMarqueeObject();

            if (didMarqueeRestart()) {
                // We need to update the values each time it restarts
                updateMarqueeFieldValues();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void initMarqueeObject() throws Exception {
        if (marqueeObject == null) {
            Field marqueeField = getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mMarquee"); // use if extending from AppCompatTextView
            // Field marqueeField = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mMarquee"); // use if extending from TextView
            marqueeField.setAccessible(true);
            marqueeObject = marqueeField.get(this);
            initMarqueeFields();
        }
    }

    private void initMarqueeFields() throws Exception {
        mStatusField = marqueeObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mStatus");
        mStatusField.setAccessible(true);
        mGhostStartField = marqueeObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mGhostStart");
        mGhostStartField.setAccessible(true);
        mMaxScrollField = marqueeObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMaxScroll");
        mMaxScrollField.setAccessible(true);
        mGhostOffsetField = marqueeObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mGhostOffset");
        mGhostOffsetField.setAccessible(true);
        mFadeStopField = marqueeObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFadeStop");
        mFadeStopField.setAccessible(true);
        mMaxFadeScrollField = marqueeObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMaxFadeScroll");
        mMaxFadeScrollField.setAccessible(true);
    }

    private boolean didMarqueeRestart() throws Exception {
        byte currentState = mStatusField.getByte(marqueeObject);
        return currentState == 0x1; // 0x1 is the byte object for the MARQUEE_STARTING state
    }

    private void updateMarqueeFieldValues() throws Exception {
        float textWidth = getWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
        float originalGap = textWidth / 3.0F;
        // We have to calculate the lineWidth based on the original value
        float originalValueStartValue = mGhostStartField.getFloat(marqueeObject);
        float lineWidth = originalValueStartValue + textWidth - originalGap;
        float mGhostStart = lineWidth - textWidth + NEW_GAP;
        mGhostStartField.setFloat(marqueeObject, mGhostStart);
        mMaxScrollField.setFloat(marqueeObject, mGhostStart + textWidth);
        mGhostOffsetField.setFloat(marqueeObject, lineWidth + NEW_GAP);
        mFadeStopField.setFloat(marqueeObject, lineWidth);
        mMaxFadeScrollField.setFloat(marqueeObject, mGhostStart + lineWidth + lineWidth);
    }
}
```

You can now easily adjust the extra blank space using the `NEW_GAP` variable.  In this example, it is set to 0 pixels.  Set that constant to any pixel value that you wish to use.

NOTE: this solution is extending from `AppCompatTextView`.  If you are extending from `TextView` you should uncomment the relevant code in the `initMarqueeObject()` method.

Then just just use this new class in place of the old TextView in XML...

```
<com.yourpackagename.CustomTextView
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

There is no need to call `setSelected(true)` in your code as this is done internally within the new class.

This may not work forever as it will break if they rename certain variables or change the logic of `TextView` in future releases.  But it has worked great on all versions that I have tested it on.

Hopefully this helps!